# "Params" not working to handle JSON parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a webservice application, which in one of my controllers there's an action that receives a POST from an external application.

Here's the log from my heroku app, which confirms that it's coming a Json data parameter:

```
2012-01-05T18:26:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/let" for 192.168.1.145 at 2012-01-05 10:26:07 -0800
2012-01-05T18:26:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by LetController#create as HTML
2012-01-05T18:26:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"Id"=>"dfe510c1-56e2-48ae-af0d-c4b265798f2e", "FormId"=>"5025", "Answers"=>[{"IdQuestion"=>"cfe0"
, "Value"=>"One", "FilledDate"=>"/Date(1325795160323-0200)/"}], "MSISDN"=>"8984223722"}
```

So, how can I access this json parameter on my method? I've tried lots of things like `params[:formid]`, `params["formid"]`, `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body)` etc etc.. and when pass to view, nothing is rendered, it's like it doesn't get anything.

Comment: [Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: I can probably answer this with a little diagnostic info. In your controller, please add: `Rails.logger.info(params.inspect)` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: before that, could you please read my comment on Finbarr answer? Do you have any idea why that could be happening? My controller it's redirecting to the right view, but it's not rendering any global variable that I'm trying to send to view :/ why?

Comment: The controller sets instance variables that are available to the view, they are not global. You say redirecting to the right view, do you mean rendering? I think we need to see your code.

Comment: Thats why you're called HOUSE isn't? eheh you're right, I was using the redirect_to method to respond, so it was redirecting to another action (the show one), and consequently the instance variable from the previous action was not there and couldn't be rendered o.O! tnx man!

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you should be able to access your params as follows:

```
params[:Id]
params[:FormId]
params[:Answers]
params[:Value]
params[:FilledDate]
params[:MSISDN]
```

Comment: Yes, tried that way, but it doesn't work.. there's something weird here: just tested on my controller @a = "aaa", and on my view <p> Params: <%= @a %>, and it's just rendering "Params:" nothing else, wtf!? :)